# Using Text from a Text File in a UITableView using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, text

What I am working on is a UITableView in Swift. I am aiming at using it as a source of navigation.
I figured out how to display text from a text file on my UITableView (see code below) But What i am finding hard to get my head around is Printing each string(Line) in a separate TableCell?

```
var FirstTableArray = [String]()
var SecondTableArray = [SecondTable]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt"){
        var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        if let content = (data){
            let myStrings = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
            FirstTableArray = myStrings[1,2,3]
        }
    }
```

`FirstTableArray = myString[1,2,3] <--` error. I'm trying to display the text in the TableView separately. atm the code prints the whole text in one whole cell.

Comment: `myStrings` will be an array.  Simply assign it to `FirstTableArray` (which should be `firstTableArray` by convention - small f)

Comment: can you be more specific please? like how exactly? I was seeing something like `cellsForSection: MyCustomCell[] = sections[indexPath!.section] as!` ..

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet..` will return an array with one line per element, so simply say `FirstTableArray=content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())` and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can use `FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]` to get the string

Comment: Ooo right ! okay makes sense. thanks will try it

Comment: @Paulw11 it was an NSCharacterSet Error would that be because It's missing the "/n" ?

Comment: The newline character set contains both \n and \r.  How is your text file delimited?

Comment: Sorry, it works good thanks paul :) it actually works the same way

Comment: @Paulw11 hey, how would you go about linking that firstTableView to the SecondTableView? I tried repeating the if statements but the app crashes.. is there another way of doing it?

Comment: How do want to 'link' them?  Is each entry in the first array a filename?

Comment: @Paulw11 so basically what I'm working on is getting a UITabView to navigate one table to another going from `topic > headings > content.` I currently have three tableViews running for the threeTables. I've got the text displaying in a table, but now to getting each `string[0]` in the text file to navigate from to another `String[0]` in another Text file. not too sure how the array would be structured?...

Comment: You would have multiple arrays, one per tableview.  Normally you use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to push a new table view in a UINavigationController to show the next level.

Comment: right :) okay, thanks for that :3 I do have one per tableView

Comment: @Paulw11 like the above code, `FirstTableArray = [String]()` and `SecondTableArray = [SecondTable]()` these are the arrays I have set for the first and second tableViews. but not too sure how i'd throw in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? actually i might have an idea. thanks for the point of direction.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it:

```
FirstTableArray = myStrings
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 let content = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(path) as String
     println(content)
```

- this allows you to print the content of the .txt file

Comment: would you know anything about UITableViews ? reading from textfile

Comment: yes i do by separate TableCell? do you mean one under the other?

Comment: not quite. Ive got that working. But I'm needing to sign each string in the textile to another string in a text file if that makes sense?